# Non pre-declared function call works for class types but not primitive types

Tags: c++, c++17, argument-dependent-lookup

In the following code

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {
    bar(T{});
}

class Something {};
void bar(Something) {}

int main() {
    foo(Something{});
}
```

(https://wandbox.org/permlink/l2hxdZofLjZUoH4q)

When we call `foo()` with a `Something` parameter, everything works as expected, the call dispatches to the `bar(Something)` overload.

But when I change the argument to an integer and provide a `bar(int)` overload, I get an error

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {
    bar(T{});
}

void bar(int) {}

int main() {
    foo(int{});
}
```

Error:

```
error: call to function 'bar' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup
```

(https://wandbox.org/permlink/GI6wGlJYxGO4svEI)

In the class case, I have not defined `bar()` in a namespace along with the definition of `Something`.  Meaning that I am not getting ADL.  Then why does the code work with class types?

Comment: Global namespace counts as a namespace for the purposes of ADL.

Answer (score 7):

> Then why does the code work with class types?

According to [§6.4.2/2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.argdep#2.1):

> The sets of namespaces and classes are determined in the following
>   way:
>
> - If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.

So upon writing `foo(int)`, the compiler will have an empty set of namespaces and classes to be considered. The call to `bar` thus must fail, as it is not declared yet. If you declare `foo(int)` on beforehand, your code will compile:

```
void bar(int);

template <typename T>
void foo(T) {
    bar(T{});
}

void bar(int) {}

int main() {
    foo(int{});
}
```

On the other hand, in the case of the `foo(Something)`, the (global) namespace will be part of the lookup, so the compiler actively scans the namespace for a function named `bar` that can be called with `Something` instances.

Answer (score 4):

Inside `foo` definition, `bar` is a dependent name because it is called with an argument that depends on a template parameter(`T`).

Dependent name resolution is performed twice [[temp.dep.res]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.res#1):

> In resolving dependent names, names from the following sources are considered:
>
> - Declarations that are visible at the point of definition of the template.
> - Declarations from namespaces associated with the types of the function arguments both from the instantiation context ([temp.point]) and from the definition context.
>     Bellow, comments show where is the point of instantiation:

```
template <typename T>
void foo(T) {  //point of definition of foo
    bar(T{});
}

class Something {};
void bar(Something) {}
void bar(int) {}

int main() {
    foo(int{});
    foo(Something{});
}
//point of instantiation of foo<int>
//point of instantiation of foo<Something>
```

For `foo<Something>` and `foo<int>` no `bar` are visible from the *point of definition*.

For `foo<Something>`, `Something` being a class its associated namespace is the namesapce in which it is declared: the global namespace. According to the second bullet, name look up is performed in the global namespace from the *point of instantiation* and `bar(Something)` is found.

For `foo<int>`, `int` is a fundamental type and it has not any associated namespaces. So no name look up is performed from the *point of instantiation*, and `bar<int>` is thus not found.